# Karma Unit Testing

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the reason for this error when trying to start karma:

```
bash-3.2$ NODE_ENV=test karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket FONtQ1oNxIxRecRxYgnS with id 73511945
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
at /public/components/angular-cookies/index.js:1
```

The index.js file contains:

```
require('./angular-cookies');
module.exports = 'ngCookies';
```

Please help!!

Comment: Can you publish your karma configuration file? It looks like something is missing...

Answer (score 5):

One way to fix this is to `npm install karma-browserify --save-dev`. That should work and you will have to do that if the actual file you need uses **require**.

`index.js` is not the actual file you need. `angular-cookies.js` is.

I find that using browserify makes debugging test errors more difficult because the stack trace you get from karma would refer to line numbers from temporary .browserify bundles that already got deleted by the time your test is done.

A simple solution is to point `files` in `karma.conf.js` directly to `angular-cookies.js` instead of using wildcards. This way, `index.js` and its usage of **require** will not cause unnecessary issue.

Answer (score 4):

require is nodejs feature
try install this [karma-browserify](https://github.com/nikku/karma-browserify), it allow you to use "require"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding browserify as a

```
preprocessor:
'test/**/*.js': ['browserify']
```

and add it to your frameworks